# Navigation bar going below what ever is inside 'col-xs-4' class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed banner at the top of my html page.  When I scroll down the idea is to have the body go underneath the top navingation banner.

It works fine except for the icons i have inside the 'col-xs-4' class.
the icons (or what ever i put inside the col-xs-4 class) seem to go over the top banner.

How can I update this so the banner is always on top.

here is link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/psj01/pen/eEydzm)

below is the html code :

```
<html>

        <head>
            <title>hello</title>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>

        .navbar {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
}


.container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

        </style>

        </head>

        <body id="top">


            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header myNavbar">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">HOME</a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse myNavbar" id="mainNavBar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#connect">CONNECT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>



            <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
                <h3>hello world</h3>
                <h3 style="color:lightblue;">say something...</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="connect">
                <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
                    <h3>Connect</h3>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="linkedIn" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="github" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="stackOverflow" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="instagram" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="medium" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-medium fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" id="codepen" target="_blank" class="social-btn"><i class="fa fa-codepen fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css:

```js
.navbar-default {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Updated **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/JyMRWW)**

---

You need to set the `z-index` so your fixed navbar appears in front of the other elements.

---

Here are some helpful docs/articles on `z-index`:

- [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)
- [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
- [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)
- [What No One Told You About Z-Index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)